# How to control create from db information

Tags: c#, sql-server, webforms, controls, custom-controls

My project have more than one pages. Suppose in one page user  need to add new control it may be any controls **like: DDL/ TextBox /Button** , User has this **flexibility** to  configure this control.My project has one **configuration** page ,there user create this custom control for specific page.In configuration page User defined bellow information

```
1)Control type.
2)control datasource
3)ControlDisplay properties
4)Control  transaction stored tables and  columns(table and column’s are  already created).
5)In UI ,Store  custom control view position related information.
6)Custom control action method(suppose user set textbox ,it’s show sum of two column of any
```

specific table ,user must define the action procedure)

To serve  above information I use bellow tables but those tables stored information failed to fulfill my requirement

[image]

Please don't show me syntax like bellow,i know how to add dynamic controls in ui,I need to store control related information in db ,then base on those information need to create control.Help me to store  control related information's like action/method procedure, view position on ui,control view information ,control datasource etc,in a word control related all information

```
Button button1=new Button();
button1.Text="dynamic button";
button1.Left=10; button1.Top=10;  //the button's location
this.Controls.Add(button1);
```

Need help to set custom control and control related information ,if anybody have better idea or any type of suggestion to solve this issue ,I will be thank full to him for his valuable information ,any type of information will be acceptable .If have any query please ask ,thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I think the simplest way to store html to database you can re-use any time and you can also get value from control when stored html page execute .you have to get value in different way 
  like in asp.net you want to get value from asp textbox you use `textbox1.Text` insted of this you have to use `Request.Form`

Comment: Anant Dabhi thanks for reply ,save control html or .aspx related tag store in db is can not solve my problem ,here i need to define action properties ,need to show control datasource ,view properties ,hope you check my problem description and problem pivotal points.thanks again for reply